# Custom audio guide

Tags: applications

I know a minister with a graveyard with significant historical value. He would like to create an audio-guide/map. Is there an iPhone application for this? Ideally, it should be:

- Free
- Have an Android version as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a little bit of research and found [GeoTour](http://www.geovative.com/features/).

It has a free plan that allows up to 10 points of interest, but if you need more, there are paid plans available.

The apps for Android and iOS are free for users wanting to go on the tour.